# How to access .data environment from code evaluated by eval_tidy

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval

I'd like to use `rlang::eval_tidy()` to evaluate a function that takes `...` in the `mtcars` namespace.

Here's an example function I'd like to evaluate, borrowed from assertr.

```
has_all_names <- function(...){
    check_this <- list(...)
    parent <- parent.frame()
    all(vapply(check_this, 
               function(x) exists(x, where = parent, inherits = FALSE), 
               logical(1)))
}
```

The base-R way to accomplish this would be:

```
fn_base <- function(expr) {
    expr <- substitute(expr)
    eval(expr, envir = mtcars, enclos = parent.frame())
}
```

But I'd like to use `eval_tidy` for the other benefits, like the `.data` pronoun. [According to the rlang documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/rlang.pdf), `enexpr` is the rlang way to `substitute`. Let's try both `substitute` and `enexpr`.

```
fn_rlang_substi <- function(expr) {
    expr <- substitute(expr)
    rlang::eval_tidy(expr, mtcars, parent.frame())
}

fn_rlang_enexpr <- function(expr) {
    expr <- rlang::enexpr(expr)
    rlang::eval_tidy(expr, mtcars, parent.frame())
}

fn_base(has_all_names("cyl", "mpg"))          # TRUE
fn_rlang_substi(has_all_names("cyl", "mpg"))  # FALSE
fn_rlang_enexpr(has_all_names("cyl", "mpg"))  # FALSE
```

What's going on? What's `eval_tidy` doing differently?

I know rlang has features to handle `...`, but in solving this, I'd prefer not to modify `has_all_names`. (The user should be able to provide an arbitrary function that takes `...` as an argument.)

Comment: I would change the title of your question since it is not about taking dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `inherits = TRUE` in your existence check because `eval_tidy()` installs the masking data one level up.

Comment: I think `inherits = TRUE` isn't a good fit here because I don't want the code to search the full environment stack. (`has_all_names` is specifically checking for objects in the parent environment, not any others.)

Is there a good way to use `parent.frame` or `sys.frame` to specifically access the data mask?

Comment: The way to access the data mask is `parent$.top_env$.data`. This is a little different than my original question, but solves the issue.

Comment: Note `.top_env` is not part of the public API so might make your code brittle, though there is no plan to remove it.